# Swapping images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a display that swaps images once clicked (from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3 and from 3 to 0 again) here's a bit of the code

**js**

```
function swap() {

    if (document.getElementById("Wins").src.endsWith('0win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins").src = "images/1win.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("Wins").src.endsWith('1win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins").src = "images/2win.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("Wins").src.endsWith('2win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins").src = "images/3win.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("Wins").src.endsWith('3win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins").src = "images/0win.png";
    }
}

function swap1() {
    if (document.getElementById("Wins1").src.endsWith('0win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins1").src = "images/1win.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("Wins1").src.endsWith('1win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins1").src = "images/2win.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("Wins1").src.endsWith('2win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins1").src = "images/3win.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("Wins1").src.endsWith('3win.png') != -1) {
        document.getElementById("Wins1").src = "images/0win.png";
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <img src="images/0win.png" id="Wins" onclick="swap()"/>
    <img src="images/0win.png" id="Wins1" onclick="swap1()"/>
</body>
```

There isn't much else I can say (i think)

Comment: I just want to recommend using `switch` instead of 4 `else if`s.

Comment: You can say whats not working with this code. Do you have any errors? Does it just silently not work? Have you attempted to debug?

Comment: endsWith is not a javascript method. use indexOf

Comment: @MauricePerry well... src.prototype.endsWith Does Exist! but thanks for the indexOf Tip :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this instead:

```
if (document.getElementById("Wins1").src.indexOf('0win') != -1) {
```

That's pure JS and probably faster

If you insist on using prototype, I think you should use `.src.prototype.endsWith(...`

---

### **UPDATE**

I made your code a little lighter and more variable/flexible/whatever.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <img id="Wins" src="images/0win.png" onclick="swap(this.src)" />
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function swap(src) {
    var num = parseInt(src.substr(src.indexOf('win')-1));

    if (num == 3) {
        num = 0;
    } else {
        num++;
    }
    document.getElementById('Wins').src = 'images/'+num+'win.png';
}
```

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/pMMSL/**

(I didn't use src-tag here because I don't have the images, but if you open your DevTools (F12) you can see the numbers from the alt-tag in the console, and you can see the alt-tag changing in the HTML

---

### **UPDATE 2**

This code is even more flexible (**http://jsfiddle.net/pMMSL/1/**):

```
function swap(src) {
    var currentFile = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var currentNum = parseInt(currentFile.substr(currentFile.indexOf('win')-1,1));

    if (currentNum == 3) {
        var newNum = 0;
    } else {
        var newNum = currentNum+1;
    }
    var newFile = currentFile.replace(currentNum,newNum);
    document.getElementById('Wins').src = src.replace(currentFile,newFile);
}
```

Comment: @Kyozumo - check out my edit, that should make your code a lot shorter, more readable, and lighter (I only did it for the first 'Wins', but you can easily copy-paste that for the other)

Comment: @Kyozumo - I made another edit to make the code even more flexible

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a non-existant String method `endsWith()`.

Use `indexOf()` instead.

If you had opened up the javaScript console, you would probably have seen this error.

You *can* create an `endsWith()` method on String however, which would make the code a little cleaner perhaps.

Check out this refactoring:

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/0win.png" id="Wins" onclick="swap('Wins')"/>
<img src="images/0win.png" id="Wins1" onclick="swap('Wins1')"/>
```

**JS**

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) {
    return this.indexOf(str) != -1
}

function swap(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el.src.endsWith('0win.png')) {
        el.src = "images/1win.png";
    } else if (el.src.endsWith('1win.png')) {
        el.src = "images/2win.png";
    } else if (el.src.endsWith('2win.png')) {
        el.src = "images/3win.png";
    } else if (el.src.endsWith('3win.png')) {
        el.src = "images/0win.png";
    }
}
```

You'll note that I pulled `document.getElementById(id)` out into a variable (`el`). This reduces a lot of code duplication. I removed more duplication by using the same `swap` function for both images. The only difference between the two was the `id`, so that was pulled out into an argument for the function.